# Script will not locate Twitter's password field

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, twitter

In this super basic python script using Selenium, I am just trying to automate my twitter login so I can begin scraping. When the chrome session opens, the username is filled out, but the password field is left blank.

```
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome();
url = "https://twitter.com/login"
driver.get(url)
assert "Twitter" in driver.title

username = driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-username-field')
username.send_keys('example_username')


password = driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-password-field')
password.clear()
password.send_keys('exmaple_password')

login_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.submit.EdgeButton.EdgeButton--primary.EdgeButtom--medium")
login_button.submit()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  It's a violation of Twitter's TOS to scrape their site; it's possible that they are blocking you in some fashion.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you need to add a `wait` on the password field. This can help if you are seeing intermittent issues with your script. I prefer to `wait` on an element rather than `sleep`.

```
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome();
url = "https://twitter.com/login"
driver.get(url)
assert "Twitter" in driver.title

username = driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-username-field')
username.send_keys('example_username')

# wait on password field
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'js-password-field')))

password = driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-password-field')
password.clear()
password.send_keys('exmaple_password')

login_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.submit.EdgeButton.EdgeButton--primary.EdgeButtom--medium")
login_button.submit()
```

Python moves through steps pretty quickly, and it takes a while for web pages to catch up sometimes. Adding a `wait` helps slow things down a bit, and can fix some intermittent errors you might be seeing.